# Can't use pagination with custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, pagination

I have a problem with custom taxonomies & post types URLs.

My post type slug is `videos`, it has an archive and it works fine: https://uwebdesign.ru/videos/. The pagination on the bottom of the page works like a charm.

My taxonomy slug is `video_type`, but I rewrite the slug to be `videos`, than all the taxonomy archives look like this: https://uwebdesign.ru/videos/podcasts/ and work fine. But the pagination is completely broken (shows 404 on the second page). Why is that?

To register taxonomy I use this code:

```
$args = array(
    'labels'            => array(), //* Not important.
    'public'            => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'description'       => '', //* Not important.
    'rewrite'           => array(
        'slug' => 'videos',
    ),
);
register_taxonomy( 'video_type', 'videos', $args );
```

All the permalink rules are flushed.

What should I do?

Comment: Please show us the code you have used to rewrite the slug.

Comment: Sure, rewrite array looks like this:
    'rewrite'  => array(
        'slug' => 'videos',
    ),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the same slug for both your `videos` custom post type and `video_type` taxonomy. Then, when querying post, WordPress don't know what to select from database.

Change your `videos` post type to `video` or something differs from `videos` taxonomy slug will solve your problem.

Comment: But then I wouldn't have cool link structure with `videos` as a foundation. Will changing post type slug to `video` but rewriting it to `videos` solve the problem?